# ERROR: Plugin 'FacebookConnectPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, sencha-touch

I am unable to use the FacebookConnectPlugin for iOS. The original App is a Sencha Touch App built with Phonegap v3.4.0-0.19.17.

What I've done so far:

1. Got the plugin working with Android
2. My config.xml has the following:

   ```
   <feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
       <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
   </feature>
   <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.4.0">
       <param name="APP_ID" value="*****" />
       <param name="APP_NAME" value="*****" />
   </gap:plugin>
   ```
3. Added the FacebookConnectPlugin.h and FacebookConnectPlugin.m under XCodeProject/Plugins/ios group
4. Added the FacebookSDK framework for iOS in the XCode project
5. Edited the Resources/MyProject.plist file adding the following entries:

   ```
   FacebookAppID: ***** 
   FacebookDisplayName: *****
   URL types
      Item 0
          URL Schemes
             Item 0: fb*****
   ```

Can you help me in getting this plugin to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Guys, I spent an excessive amount of ours trying to fix this. Finally I found the answer.
I looked at the /phonegap/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/plugin.xml

And carefully looked at this section:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="FacebookConnectPlugin">
            <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin"/>
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
        <plugin name="FacebookConnectPlugin" value="FacebookConnectPlugin"/>
        <access origin="https://m.facebook.com" />
        <access origin="https://graph.facebook.com" />
        <access origin="https://api.facebook.com" />
        <access origin="https://*.fbcdn.net" />
        <access origin="https://*.akamaihd.net" />
    </config-file>
```

So I changed my config.xml entries to look like that. Now my config.xml looks like this:

```
<feature name="FacebookConnectPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin"/>
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.4.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="785063524838258" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="Sightseaing" />
</gap:plugin>
<plugin name="FacebookConnectPlugin" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
```

And THAT DID THE TRICK!
I hope this saves someone else HOURS AND HOURS OF GOOGLING AND TRYING.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is listed in the plugin [FAQ](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#missing-facebookconnectplugin) now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using `apprequests` and can't make this plugin to work on iOS. The problem is `actionType` is required and can be even an empty string to fire out the even on iOS platform, even though on Android it works perfectly fine. The sample code would be:

```
this.options = {
  actionType: '',
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Play MYGAME with me!'
};
```

Alternatively, you can also check [issue#791 (comment)](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/791#issuecomment-531276990) with its links for more details.